# Android - Determine if LTE on API level 8

Tags: android, networking, types, subtype

I'm using the TelephonyManager on API level 8 to determine the network type and subtype. Though it does not give me an option for LTE, HSPAP, EVDO_8 and EHRPD. They're all available on API level 9+. I want my app to be usable on API level 8+. Can I and if: how can I check for those subtypes on API level 8+?

Or is it possible to only check for those subtypes if the using phone is running on that specific API level?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, there were no devices ever manufactured that are on any of those subtypes that run API Level 8. Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: Well no, but using this kind of service is not my demand. I just need to determine if it would be available to phones in a specific territory.

Comment: Hence, I'd just check it on devices running API Level 9, and assume the answer is "none of them" for API Level 8.

Comment: sorry for bother you ... but are you gone using methods which are on only in 9+ or final static variables like `TelephonyManager .NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD` ... if your answer is final static variables then, i'm really new to java, isn't final static variables are compiled inplace(`if(i == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD)` became `if(i == 14)` ? ... you should try to compile project with highest API and set minSDK to 8

Comment: yeh im gonna use final static variables like you mentioned. Already did that, Selvin. Plus I don't know if what you mentioned is right, but I could try that out. Thanks @CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare Off the top of my head, at least two LTE-capable devices shipped with earlier versions of Android: the HTC Droid Incredible shipped with API 7, and the Samsung Droid Charge shipped with API 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several LTE devices that shipped with API <9 that you might want to support. You can still access any of the new values with earlier APIs; just use the constant values instead of the variable name.  You could refer to all network types with their values if you wished.

For example, if you are looking to use `NETWORK_TYPE_LTE`, use the value `13` instead.  Here are the values implemented after API 8:

- `NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B`: 12
- `NETWORK_TYPE_LTE`: 13
- `NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD`: 14
- `NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP`: 15

[This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT) has the full list.